# Event Search results - hide Event ID and display another custom field

Tags: civievent, search-results

When results are displayed in the Manage Events default page view, is there any way to change the columns that are displayed in the results?
I'd like to hide the system generated ID field that appears to be appended to the Event Name, and add a new column that displays a custom field that I have already created.
This seems like it should be a configurable thing but I cannot seem to find where this can be done.
[image]
Thanks, Joe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find no way to configure the component dashboards via the user interface, but you may wish to make use of dashlets from your user dashboard - the following link provides instruction on how to do this: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/the-user-interface/menu-dashboard-and-dashlets/

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Drupal? If so, you can make a Drupal view for this.